# How can I make my HTML project open with the right resolution on cellphones?

Tags: html, css, mobile, bootstrap-4

So guys, recently I finished a website, I was doing it in a window, with the lowest width allowed by Chrome so it could have a nice display on cellphones, the thing is when I finally opened it in a cellphone it was displaying as a PC would display in the widest screen. For what I understand the project was already done to work in mobiles. What did went wrong in this project? How can I fix it?

Here is a picture to illustrate what I am talking about

[image]

For more details I have a link here for this project:
https://github.com/MestreALMO/MestreALMO.github.io

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare this meta tag `<meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">`.

You should try to split it in two differents meta tags :

- `<meta charset="utf-8">`
- `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">`

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote the question i didn't know about the code: <meta charset="utf-8" name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">. It took me a while but i descorvered it and thankfully it solved the problem, I forgot to display the solution here, but thank you! i did not know that i could write the meta codes in multiple lines